# How to get a second request to index from an array to start at the beginning with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to identify two different image map shape attributes. What I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to do is get the two different shapes to index the title attributes from the beginning of the array.

The code:

```
 window.slideDetails = [ 

        //Slide1    
        "C1BP7: user information",
        "FJAD7: user information",
        "FFAD7: user information",
        //Slide2
        "C0AE7: user information",
        "C7AZ7: user information",
        "FJAE7: user information",
        //Slide3
        "C1AW7: user information",
        "FJAP7: user information",
        "FFAD7: user information"

        ]; 
        $('area').each(function(index) {
            var shape=$(this).attr('shape');
              if (shape == 'rect') {
                    $(this).attr("title", window.slideDetails[index]);
              }

              else if (shape == 'poly') {
                    $(this).attr("title", window.slideDetails[index]);
              }

     });
```

It's indexing them in order So the first three 'poly' attributes get the first three in the array, then the next three attributes which are 'rect' get 4-6 and so on. I don't know enough about index & arrays, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the index incorrectly.

HTML

```
<img src="/images/testImage.jpg" width="1000" height="610" border="0" usemap="#Map1" />
<map name="Map1" id="Map1">
  <area shape="poly" coords="280,140,296,201,308,202,328,183,324,141,340,126,360,134,359,254,332,252,333,214,324,274,327,407,202,392,201,330,223,331,219,291,231,243,210,238,232,131,252,118" href="test1.htm" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="277,113,296,199,308,197,326,183,323,115,316,138,293,138" href="test2.htm" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="212,507,218,571,236,543,238,575,261,587,270,586,262,539,245,537,237,544,234,537,236,520,228,496,214,497" href="test3.htm" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="609,235,834,335" href="test1.htm" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="649,546,807,565" href="test2.htm" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="670,566,781,582" href="test3.htm" />
</map>
```

The rect and poly shapes are different parts of the image, but the first of each go the same link etc.

Comment: could you show your markup please? :0

Comment: <area shape="poly" coords="*" href="test1.htm" title="C1BP7: user information"/> <area shape="rect" coords="*" href="test1.htm" title="C1BP7: user information"/> (so that poly and rect both start from the beginning of the array individually and index the titles for rather than indexing both shapes from the one array in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing a loop that assigns an index-per-area, rather than an index-per-shape.

Instead you can use two loops (so the index gets reset on the different types of shape), and include the shape attribute as part of your [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('area[shape="rect"]')
    .each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("title", window.slideDetails[index]);
    });

$('area[shape="poly"]')
    .each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("title", window.slideDetails[index]);
    });
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mKc6T/

Comment: I thought I'd messed up with the index function, thank you for explaining it so clearly and providing a code to demonstrate where I'd gone wrong. It works perfectly. Thanks you so much. :)